# PrimeFaces 6.0 doesn't render

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm pretty new at PrimeFaces and I'm trying to learn, but I got problems about setup PrimeFaces, components doesn't render.

There is what I've tried so far.

[PrimeFaces Not Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324700/primefaces-not-rendering)

[PrimeFaces components are not rendered in browser in spite of dependency being present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462568/primefaces-components-are-not-rendered-in-browser-in-spite-of-dependency-being-p)

[Simple primefaces application not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219372/simple-primefaces-application-not-working)

Here's the code which doesn't work.

[I tried this code](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml)

Output:

[image: Output]

web.xml(Inside of WebContent/WEB-INF)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jsfmav</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sapo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsfmav</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JSFMav</name>
  
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>6.0</version>  
</dependency>  
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>

      </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Project explorer
[image: Project explorer]

Tomcat 7.0, JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 6.0

Comment: Do you have namespaces, h:head, h:body etc in xhtml? Try adding the PF repository to the pom

Comment: Yes I have. Also I added pf repository but didn't update my question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. I don't know how but It works. If someone needs more detail in the future check this out

[Here](http://www.journaldev.com/2990/primefaces-5-jsf-2-beginners-example-tutorial)

I did everything here step by step from scratch, and it worked, weird.