# primeFaces not redering components

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I Create simple project JAVAEE with maven and I create the pom.xml with all dependencies that suppose to be + clean install and the I have all the jars  but the probleme is all primeFaces components not redering 
what I do is  put the primefaces.jar file under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib then add this jar to the build path
hoop it's work and that confuse me any Ideas ?

Comment: It's hart to get an idea of what you are doing when no details are provided. Please edit your question regarding [ask] and  [mcve]

Comment: I have the same probleme in that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324700/primefaces-not-rendering/24956612#24956612           and the solution for me was  put the primefaces.jar file under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib then add this jar to the build path